# Can I create power BI report from my dot net web application?

Tags: powerbi

Can I create power BI report from my dot net web application ? I mean I don't want to create report from power BI desktop or online power BI service. I want to create power BI report from my web application.

Comment: You can embed a report in your application ( [find out more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedding)), but it still need to be created in PBI first.

Comment: You can create a report in a browser. If you try to explain better what you want to achieve, you may get better answers.

Comment: Thanks every one for your response. I want to create web application exactly like Power BI online service (https://app.powerbi.com). Is is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Microsoft did it, so you can do it too. But why do you want to reinvent the wheel? What is the added value and the problem you are trying to solve? Plus this question is way to broad and off-topic by definition.

Answer (score 0):

No, at minimum you need to be able to reference this service for the Power BI API's. Reference: [Power BI for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/what-can-you-do) and [Power BI Developer Portal](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/developers/)